# opencv find and save inner contours knowing the largest one

Tags: python, opencv, contour

How can I plot/save the inner contours of an image using python opencv?
I know how can I get the largest contour, I want to save it and the inside holes, which are contours as well.

Original Image:
[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

rgb = cv2.imread('MIL_NPGERBV2.png')
grayImg = cv2.imread('MIL_NPGERBV2.png', cv2.CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE)
#to apply properly contour algorithm we need convert to binary
(thresh, bwImage) = cv2.threshold(image, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV |     cv2.THRESH_OTSU)

 img1 = rgb.copy()
 img2 = rgb.copy()
 contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(bwImage,cv2.RETR_TREE,
                                       cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

 #show all contours
 cv2.drawContours(img1, contours, -1, (0,255,0), 2)
 out = np.hstack([img1])
 cv2.imshow('Output', out)
 cv2.waitKey(0)
 cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: Can you create a [mcve]?

Answer (score 5):

OpenCV's `findContours` method can give you the internal contours if asked politely.

It's one of the `mode` options of [`cv2.findContours()`](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#findcontours) :

> `CV_RETR_CCOMP` retrieves all of the contours and organizes them into a
>   two-level hierarchy. At the top level, there are external boundaries
>   of the components. At the second level, there are boundaries of the
>   holes. If there is another contour inside a hole of a connected
>   component, it is still put at the top level.

So asking a nice

```
myContours = cv2.findContours(myImg,cv2.RETR_CCOMP,cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
```

should give you a sort of nested object array, with the first item giving the useless outlines and the rest with the insides.

I'll try to update the answer to include a MCVE later on (but only if you update the question to include one too ^^)